# Android Textview on click in Listview

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter

Well i have made a listview populated with list_row_layout(which is populater with http json) and everyhing works cool, but i have made one Textview clickable in listview, and i give settext() onclick to that textview, but all items in listview change that text to. How can i settext on click only to clicked textview?

Here the code

this is the textview

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/acceptTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pressed"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Approve"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textColor="#0D98BA"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
```

this is the adapter class where textview is populated with serializable

```
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
     }





    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.headlineView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.acceptTV);
                    holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.high);


                    convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(position);
            holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getlow()));
            holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.gethigh()));



            holder.accept = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approveTV);


           holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View argView ) {



                   holder.approve.setText("Accepted");

                   }
               });





            return convertView;
       }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView accept;
    TextView headlineView;
            TextView reportedDateView;
            ImageView imageView;

      }
```

Comment: this is not an answer but I guess you should assign holder.accept where you assigned holder.headlineView and holder.reportedDateView. It is better for performance.

Comment: Hey, I edited my answer. I ran the code, and it works as expected. Lemme know if you've any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Add the onClickListener to your textview.
For example:

```
tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
tv2.setOnClickListener(this);
tv3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And in the onClLick:

```
@Override
onClick(View v){
    TextView tv = (TextView)v
    tv.setText("Your text");
}
```

something like this should do it.

Comment: I have already onclik    holder.accept = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approveTV);


           holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View argView ) {



                   holder.approve.setText("Accepted");

                   }
               });

Comment: The problem is that you are setting the lisener to the holder. You need to set a listener to each individual TextView

Comment: But every list item has a one same Textview and its populated with json, so all textviews with diffrent values are one same TextView, and thats problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public void onClick(View argView ) {
   ((TextView)argView).setText("Accepted");
}
```

Comment: Still it change text to another(non clicked) textviews